# Can't get a Note 3 debugging

Tags: usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm trying to use my Note 3 to help me debug a website, but I just can't get it going. I've enabled developer mode and checked USB debugging in developer options, but that's as far as I can get.

I've installed Kies 3 and when I connect my phone using a USB 3 cable to a USB 3 port I can see my phone in Kies, I can transfer files to it and everything. I can do this using Windows Explorer or Kies.

However it cannot be seen by ADB or Chrome Inspect. Going through the [instructions online](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#configure-webview) they say I should be getting a popup asking me to authorise remote debugging, but I'm not getting that.

I've tried everything I can think of, I'm new to debugging mobiles and so my knowledge on how to get this is limited. Can someone help me get this working please?

Comment: If you unplug your device, reboot, does it still not ask you for permission? You're sure you have usb debugging on? Not trying to insult your intelligence, but I've had similar problems with android devices (particular the note and note 8), and sometimes I have dev mode on, but I forgot to scroll down and check "usb debugging". I don't recall of windows has the android transfer tool, but make sure that is turned off too if it's on. The other thing is on adb try to kill and restart the server. Can't think of anything else. Have you tried any of these?

Comment: Definitely have usb debugging checked and rebooting does nothing. I've killed and restarted the adb server multiple times, both removing the usb before and leaving it plugged in during the restart.

Comment: Interestingly, I've just tried this from my home PC and the prompt came up. I can view it in adb and chrome://inspect too. It must be something about my work PC but I wonder what.

Comment: it could be the ports are blocked. Maybe you could verify with network admin, perhaps to confirm? Other than that I would recommend bashing your work computer it until it works. lol j/p

Comment: Hehe, we're a small company and I wear many hats, including network admin. There's no reason why the USB ports should be blocked.

Comment: Many corporate boxes come with ports locked, but it could be Kies running and adb etc trying to run at the same time on the same USB drivers. Try killing ALL kies processes on the work PC. Make sure you run ADB as Administrator also.

Comment: I've tried it after rebooting (Kies doesn't autostart), I checked task manager and no sign of Kies, and had no joy. One thing I think it might be is the USB drivers on the computer. Whenever I plug the phone in it says it will perform faster in a USB 3 port, even though it is a USB 3 port. It's the same with every USB 3 port on the box. I've checked device manager and it says the drivers are installed properly with no updates available, but I think that is the issue.

Comment: Just to confirm, on your personal computer you don't have kies installed? There are a lot of problems that aries with kies. It plays nice by itself, but once you want to use other toys, it becomes a problem. I actually have kies installed on my work computer for firmware stuff, but on my personal computer I removed kies and all of the drivers it installed.

Comment: No, I have Kies installed on my PC as well. I specifically installed it to create the same situation as my work PC to try and figure this out. Today I uninstalled the USB hub drivers on my work PC, downloaded the latest drivers from Dell and installed everything again, still no dice. I'll try uninstalling Kies from my work PC though.